# Log-concavity of function

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Consider the function

$$f_{n}(x)=e^{-x^2}x^n.$$

My goal is to show that

$$ G(y):=\frac{(f_2*f_0)(y)}{(f_0*f_0)(y)}- \left(\frac{(f_1*f_0)(y) }{(f_0*f_0)(y)}\right)^2$$

is log-concave.

Let us first observe that indeed $G(y) \ge 0.$

This just follows from a Cauchy-Schwarz

$$(f_1*f_0)(y) \le \sqrt{(f_2*f_0)(y)(f_0*f_0)(y)}$$

so everything is well-defined.

Usually one can say a lot when convolutions are involved about log-concavity due to standard theorems [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Operations_preserving_log-concavity)

but this combination looks a bit tricky.

***Addendum*** I should add that I am in particular very interested in theoretical insights why this particular expression has to be log-concave.

Comment: This can be done by a straight-forward calculation with help of Maple ( see the code and results here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwf335sfkxm10nx/log-concave.pdf?dl=0 ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct calculations show that 
$$(f_2*f_0)(y)=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \left(y^2+1\right),
$$
$$(f_1*f_0)(y)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} y,
$$
$$(f_0*f_0)(y)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}
$$
for all real $y$, 
so that $G$ is the constant $1/4$ and hence log concave.

Comment: thank you. although i must admit i was curious whether there is something behind my expression that explains why it has to be log-concave.

Comment: @Martinique : I doubt that a "behind-the-expression" reasoning exists, in particular given that $G$ is a constant and thus just "barely" log concave.

Comment: I should say that- although not related to log-concavity-there is some interesting structure that I noticed which I ask about in this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350524/phase-transition-in-convolution