# Matrix positive semi-definite

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, random-matrices

We construct a non-random matrix using random variables as follows:

We fix the vector $v=(1,1).$

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb R^2$-valued random variable such that $X$ is distributed according to

$$d\mu(x) \propto e^{-\Vert x-v \Vert^2-\vert x_1 \vert^4-\vert x_2 \vert^4} \ dx.$$

We then define the following matrix for $Y=X-\mathbb E(X)$

$$ \langle x,Ay\rangle = -\mathbb E\left(\langle Y,x \rangle \langle Y,v \rangle \langle Y, y\rangle\right).$$

Using wolframalpha I find that the normalization constant of this measure is $0.62,$ the expectation value of $X$ is $\mathbb E(X)=0.27 v$ and the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are non-negative.

Observations:

- It seems like any non-zero $v$ does the job, i.e. $A$ will be positive semi-definite but I am only interested in this particular choice.
- What seems to be important for this to be true is that we have the power $4$ appearing in the probability measure, as the expectation would vanish in the purely Gaussian case by symmetry.

My question therefore is: How can I show the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative?

Please let me know if you got any questions, I am happy to investigate further ideas. At the moment, I am a bit puzzled by this problem.

---

ADDENDUM to the comments:
To respond to a conjecture made in a comment:

I used the following Mathematica code

```
Plot3D[If[Sign[x1*1 + x2*1] >= 0, (Exp[-((-x1 + 0.27) - 1)^2 + ((-x2 + 0.27) - 1)^2 - (-x1 + 
      0.27)^4 - (-x2 + 0.27)^4] - 
 Exp[-((x1 + 0.27) - 1)^2 + ((x2 + 0.27) - 1)^2 - (x1 + 
      0.27)^4 - (x2 + 0.27)^4])/0.62, 0], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2,2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This produces the following plot for $\mu(-y+\mathbb E(X)) -\mu(y+\mathbb E(X))$ which shows that it is almost everywhere (up to some very small region) true that $\mu(-y+\mathbb E(X)) >\mu(y+\mathbb E(X))$ if $\langle y,v \rangle >0.$

[image]

Comment: $A = -\int_{y\in R^2} \langle y,v\rangle (y\otimes y) d\mu(y+\bar{x}) $ $= \int_{y\in R^2, \langle y,v\rangle > 0} \langle y,v\rangle (y\otimes y) (d\mu(-y+\bar{x})-d\mu(y+\bar{x}))$. I suspect that $d\mu(-y+\bar{x})-d\mu(y+\bar{x}) > 0$ when $\langle y,v\rangle > 0$. Is that true?

Comment: @YoavKallus what you write could be true and is interesting, however it is difficult to say since $\overline{x}$ is not explicit. I will try some numerics.

Comment: @YoavKallus so it is mostly true but not everywhere

Comment: @KungYao: You shouldn't call $A$ a random matrix because it is not random.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam you are right of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is strange (about the question) because, due to symmetry, the expectation of $X$ is just $(c,c)$ where $c$ is the expectation of the random variable with the density $p(x)$ proportional to $e^{-x^2-x^4+2x}$. Thus, the off-diagonal matrix elements are merely
$$
-\iint (x_1-c)(x_2-c)[(x_1-c)+(x_2-c)]p(x_1)p(x_2)dx_1dx_2=0
$$
because each of two terms splits into a product in which one of the factors is $\int (x-c)p(x)dx=0$. So why to ask about eigenvalues if the matrix is diagonal?

Similarly, the diagonal entries are 
$$
-\iint (x_1-c)^2[(x_1-c)+(x_2-c)]p(x_1)p(x_2)dx_1dx_2
\\
=-\int(x-c)^3p(x)dx,
$$
which is shown to be non-negative in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350524)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: wow, yes you seem to be right. Let me digest this post you are mentioning first, though. But just for my own understanding, would this other post also explain why it is true if you do not go into $(1,1)$ but any other non-zero direction, if it is even true?- Going through it once, it seems so and we would just have some $c_1,c_2$, would you agree?

Comment: @KungYao Yes, you'll still have the product structure though it will be $(c_1,c_2)$ and the diagonal elements will be different and have $v_1$ and $v_2$ in them, so the signs of the third central moments will flip together with the signs of $v_1,v_2$, i.e., with the sign of the $y$-parameter in that other post.

Comment: I see, so what made my question trivial, as you say, is that the individual components factorize. So let us consider the measure with density $p(x) = e^{-\langle x-v, \Sigma^{-1} x-v \rangle - \vert x_1 \vert^4-\vert x_2 \vert^4}$ where $\Sigma$ is positive-definite. Then your approach suggests to study for every $z$: $\int \langle x-c, z \rangle^2 \langle x-c, v \rangle p(x) \ dx.$ Proceeding as in your other answer leads the condition that for all $a>0$ we have $\int_{\vert \langle x,z \rangle \vert \ge a} \langle x,v \rangle p(x+c) \ dx \ge 0.$

Comment: So we can differentiate this thing with respect to $a$ and co-area formula yields a surface integral proportional to $-\int_{\vert \langle x,z \rangle \vert = \pm a} \langle x,v \rangle p(x+c) \ dx. $ This is, as far as I can tell very similar to what you were doing in the other answer. However, in the multi-dimensional case I don't think I can close the argument. Do you see how to do it?-Of course since you showed more than necessary in the other answer, this might be too much to ask for. Maybe the result is also wrong in the multi-dimensional case. Do you have any intution about this?

Comment: given your answer to the other post, I guess that is the problem you have been looking for in my post ;) I would be very curious to hear about the answer

Comment: @KungYao OK, I'll take a look, but tomorrow :-)

Comment: Thank you fedja, I appreciate the effort

Comment: so based on some numerical tests, it seems like the statement that the matrix is still positive-definite seems to be true. I am not sure though as to what extend the proof in your other post extends to the multi-variate case....

Comment: To be very precise, I am struggeling getting anywhere understanding the integral $$\int_{\langle x,z \rangle =a} \langle x,v \rangle (p(c-x) - p(c+x)) \ dx. $$ What you did in the other answer was that you argued that $c-x$ was closer to the origin that $c+x.$ This seems to be unclear in this setting, as there is no "sign" anymore.  The problem seems to be that $z$ can point in any direction and does not see the direction of $v.$ The only way this could work somehow was if the sign of $\langle x,v\rangle $ would somehow correct this "lack of a sign".  Do you see any "way out"?

Comment: @KungYao  *Do you see any "way out"?* Not yet :-(. However, I think that the scalar product of $Y$ with $v$ is a bit unnatural now because in the density we have $\Sigma^{-1}$ on the same scalar product, so I would search for counter-examples a bit more specifically looking at the cases when $\Sigma^{-1}v$ is very different from $v$ (not sure yet in what respect exactly).

Comment: good point, I checked a bit more carefully now how you arrived at the expression in the other post. It seems that in this case, the natural generalization would be to look at $$\mathbb E(\langle Y,z \rangle^2 \langle Y,\Sigma^{-1} v \rangle)$$ if I am not mistaken (instead of what I wrote). In this case we would find $$\int_{\langle x,z \rangle=a} \langle x, \Sigma^{-1} v \rangle (p(c-x)-p(c+x)) \ dx.$$ I agree it looks more "symmetric" (the weight of course is irrelevant for $\langle x,z \rangle$ as this one has to work for all $z$. Do you find this one easier to treat?

Comment: My main problem is the asymmetry between $\langle x,z \rangle=a$ and $\langle x, \Sigma^{-1} v \rangle$ in the final expression. But I will check some numerics for the new form you suggested as well and keep you posted. Thanks for thinking about this problem.

Comment: okay, i asked it as a separate question https://mathoverflow.net/q/351829/150549

Comment: I really checked this carefully numerically now, it seems to be true with the normalization you proposed, I will add the mathematica script I was using to the other question

Comment: this is to say, if one studies $\mathbb E(\langle Y,z \rangle^2, \langle Y, \Sigma^{-1}v \rangle)$ then this should be positive (according to numerics), whereas indeed $\mathbb E(\langle Y,z \rangle^2, \langle Y, v \rangle)$ fails to be. An example where the second one fails is $v=(2,-1)$ and $\Sigma^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix} 4 & 1.5 \\ 1.5 & 1  \end{matrix} \right).$ If you want me to check something numerically for you, please let me know. I am really eager to understand this better.

Comment: Dear fedja, I was just wondering whether you had developed any feeling about the question in the other thread? I would also be curious to hear some vague feelings. Unfortunately, so far nobody has commented on it...